# CAKEPHP 2 HABTM not working

Tags: cakephp

since many days i'am trying to figure out the problem .

my tables are simple i've clients table & marques table, i created a join table clients_marques with the following fields (id,client_id,marque_id ).

here is my Clients model :

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Marques' => array(
        'className' => 'Marques',
        'joinTable' => 'clients_marques',
        'foreignKey' => 'clients_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'marque_id',

    )
);
```

And here is my controller

```
public function add(){



    if($this->request->is('post')){

       $this->loadModel('Clients');     
       $this->Clients->save($this->request->data);
       $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'clients','action'=>'index'));
       //pr($this->request->data);

    }else {

        /* Chargement des Marques */
        $this->loadModel('Clients');
        $this->set('Marques', $this->Clients->Marques->find('list'));

    }

}
```

And finally the view :

```
<?php

echo $this->form->create('Clients');
echo $this->form->input('nom_client');
echo $this->Form->input('Marques');
echo $this->form->end('Ajouter');

?>
```

Nothing is working at all no multi-select for the marques il the view, no ability to save the record i'am wondering what is the real problem since i've done my best when following the documentation thank you.

Comment: you are using small letter for form instead of like this Form

Comment: doesn't fix the problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the conventions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Model names should be singular (`Client`, `Marque`), foreign keys should consist of the the lowercase underscored modelname with `_id` appended (`client_id`, `marque_id`).

HABTM variables should be camel backed plural (`marques`), and as @MoyedAnsari pointed out it should be `Form` instead of `form`.

Also you are missing a [`Model::create()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array) call.

Tip: use [bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) to generate models/controllers/views/etc.

See also

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

So your code should more look like this:

**Association**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Marque' => array(
        'className' => 'Marque',
        'joinTable' => 'clients_marques',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'marque_id',
    )
);
```

**Action** (with simplified logic)

```
public function add() {
    $this->loadModel('Client'); 

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Client->create();
        $this->Client->save($this->request->data);
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'index'));
    }

    $this->set('marques', $this->Client->Marque->find('list'));
}
```

On a side note, you should also check whether saving was actually successful!

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Client');
echo $this->Form->input('nom_client');
echo $this->Form->input('Marque');
echo $this->Form->end('Ajouter');
```